# Match elements in a dataframe to history in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that i consider history. A small scale sample is below

```
historydf
       ID  col2
    1   1     a
    2   1     c
    3   1     c
    4   1     e
    5   2     a
    6   2     b
    7   2     b
    8   2     e
    9   3     a
    10  3     a
    11  3     b
    12  3     c
    13  4     b
    14  4     a
    15  4     a
    16  4     c

testdf

      col1
    1    a
    2    a
    3    b
    4    e
```

I want to know if i can match test df to find an exact or the closest match within history df and output the ID(s).

I have a few conditions that must be met.

1. The test df cannot be matched in full against the history. It can be
   element by element or even more than 1 element by element. But it
   cannot be the whole df at once.
2. The sequence of match is important to get as close to the history.

A sample output step by step is below. In my case I am considering element by element due to the small scale of the sample.

testdf$col1[1] is "a". There are no prior elements so this is the start of the sequence. Since "a" appears in all IDs the output will be: ID = 1,2,3,4

testdf$col1[2] is "a". The prior element was "a". Now we look for "a" preceded by "a". Since "a","a," appears in 2 IDs the output will be: ID = 3,4

testdf$col1[3] is "b". The prior element was "a". Now we look for "b" preceded by "a". Since "a","b," appears in 1 ID the output will be: ID = 3

Now that only one ID remains the matching can stop and the final output is ID 3 is closest match to testdf.

It is important to note that the search parameter in history can be narrowed down with each successful match. For example during the second match in the above example the history can be narrowed down to only ID 3 and 4.

Hopefully the question is clear and I would appreciate any help as long as it follows the two conditions i mentioned.

Comment: (1) "_Now we look for "b" preceded by "a"._" Isn't this true for ID 2 as well (row 5 and 6)? (2) Can you please clarify the sentence "_Now that only one ID remains the matching can stop and the final output is ID 3 is closest match to testdf._" (3) Why don't you check `testdf$col1[4]`, "e" preceded by "b"?

Comment: "_It is important to note that the search parameter in history can be narrowed down with each successful match._". Can you please clarify _how_ it is "narrowed down".

Comment: @Henrik I didn't check the 4th element because the closest match, 3, had already been found. The objective is to find a match (closest or exact) using the least amount of elements. I dont have an exact answer to narrow down. But I've seen filter from dplyr as a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I would approach your problem by defining a *similarity score*; please take a look at the details and code I give below, and perhaps do some testing to see if this is consistent with your expected output for your actual data.

The solution involves the following approach:

1. Form the combination `combn` of successive `col1` elements from `testdf`

   ```
   combn <- rev(sapply(rev(seq_along(testdf$col1))[-1],
       function(i) paste0(testdf$col1[i-1], testdf$col1[i])));
   combn;
   #[1] "a"  "aa" "ab"
   ```

   You can see that this corresponds to the three cases you test for in your example: (1) the first `"a"`, (2) `"a"` preceded by `"a"`, and (3) `"b"` preceded by `"a"`.
2. We now group entries in `historydf` by `ID` and summarise entries in `col2` by pasting characters together in column entries `ss` (one per `ID`). We then calculate a row-wise `score` by summing the number of *matches* of every `combn` element with `ss`; the larger the `score` the more matching successive entries from `col1` are present in `historydf$col2`. We then simply extract the row with the largest score, and `pull` the corresponding `ID` (`ID = 3` in your case).

   ```
   historydf %>%
       group_by(ID) %>%
       summarise(ss = paste(col2, collapse = "")) %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(score = sum(sapply(combn, function(x) sum(grepl(x, ss))))) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       filter(score == max(score)) %>%
       pull(ID)
   #[1] 3
   ```

Comment: I like this answer. But I have some questions. Is there a way to vary the combinations? for example if i want 3 elements in sequence instead of 2. The other is that one of my conditions was that the testdf should not be matched all at once against historydf.

Comment: @Nix Extending the code to check for 3-mers is straightforward. I'm not sure about the role/effect of the other condition. Can you provide an example (with expected output) where my code does *not* give the correct result? I'm still not entirely clear on your exact problem statement, but this is probably due to our different ways of formulating/articulating the problem. I think the best way forward would be to do some testing with various sample data.

Comment: I think the best way I can explain is text auto-complete. As you're typing a word in search it keeps trying to auto complete the word before you finish typing it. I would like the same here. Start matching from the beginning of testdf without using the whole testdf. Some ways i thought of doing this is to loop the code or rollapply but I'm unsure of how to proceed with either way.